# How to get user specific data in Firebase Swift 3

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data of current user in the application. How can I do that. ?

Here is my current user's firebase id :

[image]

And my table node is :

[image]

Here it is clear that my `uid` and nodes title are different. So how can I get particular user's data.

My code till now:

```
self.ref =  Database.database().reference()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
self.ref.child("member").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
 if !snapshot.exists() {
                    // handle data not found
                    return
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting different IDs, because the first one `Wnlxl...` is the `userID` and the other `-KVvR664...` is an `autoID`.
You have set `.childByAutoID` following the `member`, if you want to retrieve the data of the current user then, you have to put `userID` following `member`.
Then you can easily retrieve the user's data by `userID` because each and every detail will be saved under `userID`.
Hope this code will work for you.

```
let ref : FIRDatabaseReference!
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()    
ref.child("member").child(user!.uid).setValue(["name": self.fullName.text!, "email": self.email.text!, "mobile": self.mobile.text!, "doj": self.doj.text!])
```

Comment: I don't want to set values but fetch the details of current user

Comment: you have set `.childByAutoID` following the `member`, if you want to save the details under `UserID` then you must add `userID` following `member`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase screenshot is incorrect I think - your code will work fine, but how you create these members are wrong.

When creating the members you are saying `.childByAutoID` which you should be using `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`. If that makes sense. Let me know.

Edit: to create a user with userUID data in the node member do the following:

```
if let userUID = Auth().auth.currentUser?.uid{
   ref.child("members/\(userUID)").setValue(*YOURMEMBERINFODICTIONARY*)
}
```

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: The screenshot you posted. Post the firebase call that is creating the member and I can explain.